# Scheme function to write numbers up and down from x

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm not sure what the best way to phrase this is, so I'm just going to show an example.

(high-low 4) -> (0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0)

(high-low 0) -> (0)

```
(define low 
(λ (a)
   (cond
       [(zero? a) '()]
       [else (cons (sub1 a) (low (sub1 a)))])))
```

I think that the best way to do this is to break it up into 2 separate functions and call them in the main function. The code above is the second part of the function but I'm struggling to define the high part of it (0-a)

Any help is welcome 
(This is not homework, I'm just interested in learning how Scheme works).

Comment: you've been spoiled with excellent answers from some of the best schemers on SO ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to learn, I guess you don't want to use a lot of utility functions, so I will help with your `high`. Notice that there are two things when you want to construct the list: the starting number and the ending number.

For `low`, it's easy because the ending number is a literal 0, while the starting number changes, so you can keep track by using only one variable.

For `high`, the starting number needs to be changed in every iteration like in `low`. However, the ending number is not a literal (though it is constant), so we will need its information. Therefore, we will add the ending number as one of the arguments of the function. That is, we expect

```
(high 1 10) ; evaluates to (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

The body then would be:

```
(define high
  (λ (start stop)
    ...))
```

The terminating condition is when `start` goes beyond `stop`. This is the base case where the answer is `'()`.

```
(define high
  (λ (start stop)
    (cond
      [(> start stop) '()]
      ...)))
```

Otherwise, `start` is less than or equal to `stop`. The answer, a list starting from `start` and ends at `stop`, is the same as `start` attaching to the front of a list starting from `(add1 start)` and ends at `stop`. That is:

```
high start stop = [start start+1 start+2 ... stop] 
                = [start] + [start+1 start+2 start+3 ... stop]
                = [start] + high start+1 stop
```

Thus:

```
(define high
  (λ (start stop)
    (cond
      [(> start stop) '()]
      [else (cons start (high (add1 start) stop))])))
```

Comment: Very educational approach. These are the best answers, imo.

Answer (score 2):

How about using built-in list procedures? it'll be a lot easier, an besides, it's the recommended way to think about a solution when using Scheme, which encourages a functional-programming style of coding:

```
(define (high-low n)
  (let ((lst (build-list n identity)))
    (append lst
            (cons n
                  (reverse lst)))))
```

For example:

```
(high-low 4)
=> '(0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0)
```

Comment: I'm impressed with the variety of solutions here. I particularly like this one.

Answer (score 2):

`#!racket` (aka `#lang racket`) has a `range` procedure so if you have the power of racket at your hands you can just do:

```
(define (high-low n)
  (append (range n)         ; 0 to n-1
          (range n -1 -1))) ; n to 0
```

If you want to roll your own recursive loop you can think of it as building a list in reverse starting at zero increasing by one until a limit, then decreasing until zero. The step changes and when your current value is equal to the end value and your direction is decreasing you are one element from the finish line.

```
(define (high-low n)
  (let loop ((cur 0) (limit n) (step add1) (acc '()))
    (cond ((not (= cur limit)) ; general step in either direction
           (loop (step cur) limit step (cons cur acc)))
          ((eq? step add1)     ; turn
           (loop cur 0 sub1 acc))
          (else                ; finished
           (cons cur acc)))))
```

I guess there are numerous ways to skin this cat and this is just one tail recursive one.

Comment: Very nice @Sylwester. Always pleased to read contributions from you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple more options.  Using `named let` and `quasi-quote`...

```
(define (high-low n)
  (let hi-lo ((i 0))
    (if (= i n) `(,i) `(,i ,@(hi-lo (+ i 1)) ,i))))
```

...another option using `do`:

```
(define (high-low2 n)
  (do ((i (- n) (+ i 1))
       (out '() (cons (- n (abs i)) out)))
      ((> i n) out)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather over-general solution, built on a function which builds lists in a rather general way.  It has the advantage of being tail-recursive: it will build arbitrarily long lists without exploding, but the disadvantages of needing to build them backwards and of being somewhat obscure to understand.

Here is the function:

```lisp
(define (lister base inc stop cont)
  ;; start with a (non-empty) list, base;
  ;; cons more elements of the form (inc (first ...)) to it;
  ;; until (stop (first ...)) is true;
  ;; finally call cont with the resulting list
  (define (lister-loop accum)
    (if (stop (first accum))
        (cont accum)
        (lister-loop (cons (inc (first accum)) accum))))
  (lister-loop base))
```

(Note this could obviously use named-let for the inner function.)

And here is a function using this function, twice, to count up and down.

```lisp
(define (cud n)
  ;; count up and down
  (lister '(0)
          (λ (x) (+ x 1))
          (λ (x) (= x n))
          (λ (accum)
            (lister accum
                    (λ (x) (- x 1))
                    zero?
                    (λ (a) a)))))
```

And then:

```
> (cud 10)
'(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0)
```

---

Note that this was written using Racket: I think that is is pretty portable Scheme except that I have called `lambda` `λ` and perhaps Scheme does not have `first` and so on.